# Connect to SQL Server using IP address

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=IPaddress,port; DATABASE=Databasename)
```

SQL Server remote connection settings are allowed. Is there anything else I haven't done or the code is wrong？
What to fill in id and password?

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=192.168.1.89; Port=1433; uid=yourusername; pwd=yourpassword; DATABASE=Databasename; Trusted_Connection=No;')
```

Server= must be your IP Address to your SQL Server
Port is optional and make sure if you specify make it 1433 only cause sql server works on 1433 port